# What is causing this command line error?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, unix

I am trying to programatically call the "top" command. The following is the code used:

```
char buffer [128];
char* threadsPointer;
char* procPointer;
NSString* numberOfThreadsString;
NSString* numberOfProcString;
FILE* output = popen("/usr/bin/top", "r");

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), output) != NULL)
{
    if ((procPointer = strstr(buffer, "Processes:")) != NULL)
    {
        procPointer += strlen("Proceses: ");
        strcpy(buffer, procPointer);
        numberOfProcString =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String: buffer];
    }

    if ((threadsPointer = strstr(buffer, "sleeping,")) != NULL)
    {
        threadsPointer += strlen("sleeping, ");
        strcpy(buffer, threadsPointer);
        numberOfThreadsString =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String: buffer];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Proc: %@\nThreads: %@\n\n\n", numberOfProcString, numberOfThreadsString);
```

Instead of giving valid output, I keep getting the error: "Error opening terminal: unknown". I commended out the whole piece of code to identify the problem, and realized that its the line: `FILE* output = popen ("/usr/bin/top", "r");` that is causing the error.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong? Note I am on Mountain Lion OS X building an app for OSX not iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try "top  -l 1".

"-l 1" mean 1 sample, I think it should run top in non-interactive mode, print the result and exit.

On linux the command is "top -n 1" ("-n 1" mean run only 1 iteration, which should be equivalent to "top -l 1" on mac osx).

Answer (score 5):

`top` on MacOSX requires that its standard output or standard error be connected to a valid terminal to run. When you invoke it without a terminal (or a `$TERM` environment variable set to a valid terminal name, like "vt100"), it gives you that error: **Error opening terminal: unknown**.

You really shouldn't be using `top` for this, since it's an interactive program that requires a terminal. You should just be using `ps`.

Comment: ps doesn't provide the information I need- the total number of running threads and processes. top is my only option. How would I connect the standard output to a valid terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific information or all the details you should use "/proc" filesystem.

You can readdir() and fopen() all the files in /proc which contains currently running processes and get a lot of information, like for example what files are open by some process, or what ports is the process listening on.

'top' command opens a terminal and waits for user input. You won't be able to use it in a an automated script